# link hover not working

Tags: css, class, hyperlink, hover

```
a.f_pc {
color:#2972b0;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
}

a.f_pc:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
    }


<p><a href="faq.html" class="f_pc">learn more</a></p>
```

could anyone tell me why the hover does not work when I mouse over the link?  Thanks

Comment: Could have been overriden by a more specific style?

Comment: can you provide a demonstration of this in jsFiddle? I don't see anything wrong with the CSS you've provided but there may be other factors at play in your HTML or elsewhere in the CSS.

Comment: As it is in your question, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/DQNSb/3/

Comment: Thanks.  I just checked your fiddle, James and i'm checking my code as Daryl suggested.  i'm not using the "a" element or the class anywhere else in my CSS, but the hover is not working in any browser. I can't figure it out...

Comment: Above code works fine. Nothing wrong with it. Probably you might referencng the `CSS` incorrectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's got to be getting overridden by something, if you could post the full css/html, it would be possible to figure out what was going on.  You could try adding !important to the rule to override it, though I'd still recommend getting to the root cause of it.

```
a.f_pc:hover {
  text-decoration:underline !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know your problem got solved a long time ago, but I was searching for answers and my code had the same problem. In my case the problem was that I was using a pseudo-element of :visited before the :hover, that was causing an override for some reason.

I solved by putting under the visit, so the hover rule reads after, and now it's working, if someone is having this problem as well, it can be the issue!

How I did it:

```
.watchlist-link,
.watchlist-link:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
    
.watchlist-link:hover {
    color: #ff4444;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

p styling may be overriding it, try it without it and see if it works.

Comment: `#f_mainContent_left p {
 line-height:1.4em;
 padding-bottom:15px;
 font-size:.8em;
 padding-top:3px;
}`  I removed the "p" but it still didn't work.  here is css for the "p"

Comment: Remember reading something about the DOCTYPE declaration effecting a hover before. Have you declared the DOCTYPE?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` this is doctype (auto in dreamweaver cs 5.5)

Comment: kasun, i am referencing the css correctly.  all other styles show and i only have one css file in my css directory on the root of my index.html page:  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/f_hope.css" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Take it in just other page and your css working well. But it not working in your file means it might be overriding for other css. Take help from firebug.